# Install service from windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button that allows the user to browse a file and then stores the path + filename in a variable:

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
string filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
```

After browsing for the .exe, I want to install the service.

Currently we run a bat as admin using installutil. It can be done also with sc create, from an administrator command prompt.

What is the easiest way to install a service from the windows form?

Can I create a string like:

```
sc create "servicename" binpath="filepath"
```

and run it from the program?

The other option I was thinking about was to make the program create a bat and run it as admin?

Comment: Look at [Process.Start()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to install a service:

Note: you will need to add a reference to `System.ServiceProcess`

```
public static void InstallService(string serviceName, Assembly assembly)
{
    if (IsServiceInstalled(serviceName))
    {
        return;
    }

    using (AssemblyInstaller installer = GetInstaller(assembly))
    {
        IDictionary state = new Hashtable();
        try
        {
            installer.Install(state);
            installer.Commit(state);
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                installer.Rollback(state);
            }
            catch { }
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public static bool IsServiceInstalled(string serviceName)
{
    using (ServiceController controller = new ServiceController(serviceName))
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceControllerStatus status = controller.Status;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

private static AssemblyInstaller GetInstaller(Assembly assembly)
{
    AssemblyInstaller installer = new AssemblyInstaller(assembly, null);
    installer.UseNewContext = true;

    return installer;
}
```

You just need to call it like:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath);
InstallService("name", assembly);
```

Comment: I got it to work. The following error is appearing.

'An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Configs.exe'

Comment: @TiraULTI is the app running as admin?

Comment: by running as admin do you mean open it as an admin? If so then yes

Comment: I'm assuming the app you are trying to install implements `ServiceBase` and `Installer` somewhere in it? i.e. it is a service

Comment: The app I am trying to install is a windows service. It was not coded by me, it was made by another part of our team.

Comment: @TiraULTI Have you tried the other answer? The code above isn't fully tested although I have used it to install the current app. I.e. install itself not another app installing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"sc create \"servicename\" \"{0}\"", filepath);
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

The line `startInfo.Verb = "runas";` enables the process to start under administrator privileges.

Comment: Are you sure about this part? 

String.Format(@"sc create \"servicename\" \"{0}\"", filepath);

I do not understand where tu put the name.

Comment: @TiraULTI well that's the command you pass to install the service so use whatever you want there, for example in the question you said `sc create "servicename" binpath="filepath"` so you could pass that as the `startInfo.Arguments`, obviously with the correct servicename and filepath set.

Comment: `startInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"sc create 'name12' binpath='"+filePath+"'");`

Now its compiling, when I search for the exe and select it, the only thing it does is to open the cmd.